# Testing Task-based WCF call

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, task-parallel-library, rhino-mocks

I am converting the WCF calls I am making in an application to run asynchronously to ensure the GUI is responsive while it gets data. Mostly I am using these methods to populate the properties of a ViewModel.

For instance, here's my old and new code:

```
private async Task LoadDataItems()
{
    //DataItems = Service.SelectDataItems();

    DataItems = await Service.SelectDataItemsAsync();
}
```

Also, here's some test code using RhinoMocks:

```
//Doesn't set DataItems when LoadDataItems() is called
myWcfServiceClient.Stub(async client => await client.SelectDataItemsAsync()).Return(new Task<List<DataItemDto>>(() => new List<DataItemDto> { testDataItem }));

//NullReferenceException on SelectDataItemsAsync()
myWcfServiceClient.Stub(client => client.SelectDataItemsAsync().Result).Return(new List<DataItemDto> { testDataItem });
```

Basically, in my unit test, either `DataItems` isn't set or I get a NullReferenceException trying to fake out the result. This is probably as much a question on RhinoMocks than anything...

Answer (score 1):

In RhinoMocks, you define the `Result` on the Task-based operation with `Task.FromResult(...)`

So, my test code would set up the result as follows:

```
myWcfServiceClient.Stub(client => client.SelectDataItemsAsync()).Return(Task.FromResult(new List<DataItemDto> { testDataItem }));
```

Simple and works great!